# react-select-show label + value when a label is selected from dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a use case in my UI where for react-select component I want to show label in the dropdown but when we select the label, the selected option shown should be label + value.
How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `formatOptionLabel` prop to create your layout for your 'selected' option (the display in the search field), but use a custom `Option` layout for the display of your 'option's (or, conversely, use the prop to create your 'option' layout and provide a custom `SingleValue` or `MultiValueLabel` component for the display in the search field).

The documentation tells you [how to apply custom components](https://react-select.com/components).